# Repetition of same number using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to understand how recursion works, I am starting it with simple example, I understand it with simple factorial program but when I add more than one line of code its hard to understand how its working.

Below is my code:

```
public class ProceduralProgramming {

    public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     fact(3);

}
    public static void fact(int n)
    {
        if (n>=1)
        {
            fact(n-1);
            fact2(n);
            fact(n-1);   
        }
    }
    public static void fact2(int n)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
1
2
1
3
1
2
1
```

I am confused with the repetition of `1`, Why and how this repetition coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to put informative strings in your method calls to aid in following what is going on.  You can adjust these as you see fit and put in other things like spacing and indentation.  This is just to give you an idea.

```java
    public class ProceduralProgramming {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          fact("Initial fact call : ", 3);
       }
       public static void fact(String note, int n) {
          System.out.println("Entered Fact - " + note + n);
          if (n >= 1) {
             fact("First fact call : ", n - 1);
             System.out.println("returned from first fact call");
             fact2("Fact2 call : ", n);
             System.out.println("returned from fact2 call");
             fact("Second fact call : ", n - 1);
             System.out.println("returned from second fact call");
          }
       }
       public static void fact2(String note, int n) {
          System.out.println(note + n);
       }
    }
```

Second example of returning from a recursive call.

```java
     public static void doit(int n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Value of n before call: " + n);
        doit(n-1);
        // previous n's will be listed here in reverse order.
        System.out.println("Value of n when returning: " + n);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. `returned from first fact call` `Fact2 call : 2` How this 2 come?

Comment: The n decrements for each call to fact.  But when you return, it sort of unwinds and the previous values are returned.  See my edited example above.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call `fact(n-1)` you are jumping back to the top of the `fact()` function, and your current iteration of `fact()` is on the 'stack'; waiting for the next iteration to finish:

```
fact(3-1) calls fact(2) which calls fact(1) which calls fact(0)
                                    fact(1) -> continues, prints 1 and calls fact(0)
                fact(2) -> continues, prints 2, calls fact(1) which calls fact(0)
                                                      fact(1) -> continues, prints 1, calls fact(0)

etc...
```

A big help would be to download a proper IDE and learn to use the Debugger, which allows you to go through a program line by line and see the current value.  Check out [IntelliJ Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows).